# Android Show Dialog not working only the screen fades out

Tags: android

I am trying to call a dialog window from a fragment with single choice selection list, but when I hit the button only the screen fades out nothing showing up...

Calling function:

```
private void showDialog() {
    myDialog dialog = new myDialog();
    dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"dialog");
}
```

Dialog class:

```
public class Dialog extends DialogFragment {

    final String[] items= {"item 1","item 2","item 3"};
    String selection;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Choose One").setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which){
                    case 0:
                        selection = items[which];
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        selection = items[which];
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        selection = items[which];
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "item selected: " + selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: try with dialog.setCancellable(false);

Comment: @LucaNicoletti if I do that in my call function I still can not see the list, and I was not able to return after the screen fades out... : (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onCreateDialog` you should return the `Dialog` that you created:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Choose One").setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case 0:
                    selection = items[which];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    selection = items[which];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    selection = items[which];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "item selected: " + selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Rename your class `Dialog` to `CustomDialog` or something similar because it is already used.
You can show it doing:

```
private void showDialog() {
    CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog();
    dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"dialog");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not return `super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)` but the `builder.create()`